# Will content of std::vector<std::string> be moved when it is assigned as R-value?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

Please look at code below (shown in briefly):

```
std::vector<std::string> foo( ... /some params/ ... )
{
      std::vector<std::string> retVec;
      /.../
      return retVec; // --- (1)  assume R.V.O happens
}
//code block where we use foo function(neglect scoping just function call)
const auto content_1 = foo( ...);  --- (2)
const auto& content_2 = foo( ... ); --- (3)
const auto&& content_3 = foo(...); --- (4)
```

Even R.V.O(Return Value Optimization) at line **(1)** should we explicitly call ***std::move***  function on line  **(2)** as below in order to move content of return vector to **content_1**.

```
 const auto content_1 = std::move(foo( ...)); --- (2)
```

or afterwards Compiler code analysis and then Optimization kicks in and move content of returned std::vector from foo to **content_1** ?

- If compiler optimized this,will it happens to any vector, whose type can
  be move construable and move assignable?
- At line number **(3)** and **(4)** data move operation won't happen
  theoretically?

Comment: If there's RVO there's no move.

Comment: @juanchopanza assume we call foo function as a function parameter - 
 <code> bar( foo( ... ) ) </code> R.V.O happens exactly, but what happens actually we assign  returned vector to another vector (except aliasing and referencing)  std::vector<std::string> xObj = foo( ... );  firstly R.V.O happened then data move ?  or compiler reduce operations directly to data move operation ?

Comment: If you *assign* then the move assignment operator is called, because expression`foo()` is an rvalue. There has to be something to move from.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for the first case you don't need to move, because the returned value is already a prvalue, and there is no need to concert it to a rvalue, because it already is one.

If the compiler optimizes this (it has to starting with C++17), the there will be no move. You are right that in the last two cases, no copy or move will happen and the compiler will not elide the call, because the returned vector has its lifetime extended.

Comment: Is this valid for even std::string ? for an example 
std::string xObj = std::string("Should")+" this "+ std::string("move");
 that newly constructed string in r.h.s ("Should this move ") move automatically to xObj since it's a rvalue?
no meaning of calling std::string xObj =  std::move(std::string("Should")+" this "+ std::string("move")); ?

Comment: @Buddhika Exactly, you don't need to move rvalues, because they already have implicit move semantics. Only for lvalues you need to `std::move` which would cast the lvalue to an rvalue